# django select2 chained dropdown menu

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-select2

I am new to Django and trying to get familiar with it.

I have two dropdown menu's which are chained. I want to select a country, and from there I want to choose the city from that country.

I am trying to replicate the code from this website: 
https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html#chained-select2

I  have the following models in models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name="cities", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My views.py has the following code:
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django import forms

```
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget

from .models import Country, City
# Create your views here.

class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        label=u"Country",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Country,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
    )

    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=City.objects.all(),
        label=u"City",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=City,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
            max_results=500,
        )
    )

def start(request):
    form = AddressForm()
    return render(request, 'startpagina.html', {'form': form})
```

My HTML has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chained</title>
{{ form.media.css }}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<table>
    {{ form }}
</table>
<br>
{{ form.media.js }}
</body>
</html>
```

I populated my country and city models with the following values:
Country: name: Nederland 
Country: name: belgie
City: name: Amsterdam, country: Nederland
City: name: Rotterdam, country: Nederland 
City: name: Antwerpen, country: belgie
City: name: Brussel, country: Belgie

When i run my django project I do get 2 dropdown menu, but unfortunately they are not linked. This means that when I select Nederland I don't get Amsterdam and Rotterdam, but I get all the cities.

Can somebody tell me what i am missing in my code to get the 2 dropdown menu's linked?

Comment: You can easly do this task using jQuery.

Comment: I am not that familiar with JQuery. I just started webprogramming. What i understood from reading the django_select2 documentation is that they also use that. But it is all internally regulated. I am getting 2 dropdownmenu's but they are not chained. I think that i am missing something very small.